# Background-clip fix for IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design

I am using `background-clip: content-box;` on a responsive layout of square boxes (Metro Style).

The `background-clip` property is used to display a fake margin between each box so that when resizing the browser, the margin stays the same.

I am struggling to find a hack/fix to get this property working in IE8. I have tried Pie HTC but this did not seem to affect the boxes.

Here is a basic jsfiddle of my issue in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4393/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately IE6-IE8 do not support rounded borders. Instead you would need to use something like CSS3PIE.

IE9 however DOES understand

```
 border-radius
```

Here is a quick step-by-step (this is a very simple, high-level sample.

1. Download CSS3PIE at http://css3pie.com/download-latest
2. Save the .htc file in the root of your site
3. Lets say you have a div with the id of foo:

`<div id="foo">Hello, I'm rounded</div>`

Your CSS for this could be:

```
#foo { width: 500px; height: 200px; background: blue; -moz-border-radius: 12px; /* FF1-3.6 */
       -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android <1.6 */
       border-radius: 12px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */  }
You simply need to add one more rule to the bottom of that CSS, as follows behavior: `url(/PIE.htc);`
```

This will cause CSS3 to apply your border-radius rules to IE6-8.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I am not wanting to round the corners. I am wanting to use `background-clip: content-box` on the boxes to allow for the 'fake' margin.

Comment: Ok ok... I will give a solution

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I fixed this by adding an inner div and setting the background on that and the `div.box` to transparent!

Thanks.

Comment: so it means there is no proper solution for it?